# Is Shadow faster than Sonic?

Tags: sonic-the-hedgehog

I know this is a well-known question. But, is it possible Shadow is faster than Sonic? I mean, it could be. Due to my research on Google and stuff, I've probably found out how Shadow is faster. So, Shadow has these wheels at the bottom of his shoes. Correct? From that I've realized that his wheels help him go fast, even as fast as Sonic. Though it hasn't been said by sega or the curator of Sonic, it still could be true. Whenever Sonic is running he is running about 3000 miles per hour right? So, how fast does Shadow go? Well, from [my research](https://curiosity.com/topics/darkness-is-faster-than-the-speed-of-light-curiosity/) I got

> "299,338 kilometers per second
>   The speed of light is 186,000 miles per second (299,338 kilometers per second). So if it takes you less than half a second to move your hand that distance, then that shadow will have "broken" the speed of light."

I’m unsure if whoever made that is talking about a actual Shadow or Shadow the hedgehog, but even if they weren't this could be true. But, compare 3000 mph to 299,338 kps. Who is faster?? Im horribly confused about this! Do you guys know? :)

Comment: If I did the math right, Shadow travels (based on your research) 1,077,616,800 km/h. While I don't have the conversion between mile and km handy, pretty sure that is more than Sonic.

Comment: The linked article appears to have nothing to do with Sonic the Hedgehog.

Comment: Nobody can beat Sonic. Metal Sonic also tried that, but he failed. In small bursts, Sonic can be beaten, but Sonic has got endurance. He can run continuously in super high speed for very long.

Answer (score 8):

In some media Shadow is described as being *identically fast*.

> **SHADOW THE HEDGEHOG**
>
> Created in secret to be the ultimate life form, and was actually
> created by Professor Gerald. He can easily rival Sonic’s abilities in
> terms of both speed and power.
>
> <sub><sup>[Sonic Sega All Stars Racing Manual](http://file:///C:/Users/Richard/Downloads/SR_PS3_MAN%20INT_9.pdf)</sup></sub>

---

> [image]
>
> <sub><sup>Sonic Generations Profile card</sup></sub>

---

> [image]
>
> <sub><sup>Sonic Heroes Manual</sup></sub>

---

That being said, the manual for [Sonic Rivals on the PSP](http://www.gamesdatabase.org/Media/SYSTEM/Sony_PSP/Manual/formated/Sonic_Rivals_-_2006_-_Sega.pdf) explicitly states that Sonic is the "fastest living" being in the Universe.

[image]

And Sonic and Shadow directly discuss their relative speeds in [Sonic Chronicles:  The Dark Brotherhood](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sonic_Chronicles:_The_Dark_Brotherhood)

> **Sonic:** *You can't outrun me Shadow.*
> **Shadow:** *I can outfight you.*

The implication being that Shadow's speed is inferior, if only marginally.